# How to interpret the fixed effects in relation to random effects in mixed effects model?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, panel-data

This is a small subset of my data to show what it looks like because my data set is too large:

I want to compare the long-term effect of two types of surgery on weight loss.
In my real data set `285 people` get `treatment B` and `49 people` get `treatment A`.
The patients are followed for a maximum of `10 years`, they do not have the same follow-up time, I decide to do a `linear mixed effect model`. With this subset, the model does not seem to converge. But it does converge with my whole (real) data set. And the result I present is the result of my data set.

The outcome is `BMI` (body mass index), the predictor is `treatment`. I adjust for `gender`.
The individual will be in the `random effect` (`ID`).
I set the random intercept and slope.
I wonder if I should put the `time effect` in my model or not? Why do people put the time effect in their model? And what is the underlying assumption?

Here is how I implement my model. Is it correct?

```
lmer.bmi <- lmer(BMI ~ Treatment + Gender + 
     (1 + Treatment|ID), 
     data =mydataBMIsample)
```

Below are the results:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: BMI ~ Treatment + Gender + (1 + 
  Treatment | ID)
   Data: mydataBMI

REML criterion at convergence: 12636.9

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.9505 -0.6039 -0.2686  0.1999  4.4135 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 ID       (Intercept) 30.84    5.554         
          TreatmentB  48.97    6.998    -0.90
 Residual             34.63    5.885         
Number of obs: 1926, groups:  ID, 334

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  34.7613     0.8879  39.152
TreatmentB   -3.2226     0.9160  -3.518
GenderMale   -0.4578     0.5679  -0.806

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
           (Intr) TrtmnB
TreatmentB -0.957       
GenderMale -0.092 -0.040
```

I have some difficulty interpreting the results of the mixed effects model.
I know from the fixed effects that patients with treatment B have a lower BMI.
Is it correct to say that people with `treatment B` have a `BMI 3 points lower` than those with `treatment A`? If I understand correctly, the fixed effect should be interpreted in relation to the random effect.
But what will the random effect change in the interpretation of the effect size of the treatment (the fixed effect) if only to give an indication of the veracity of that effect size ?

Here below reproducible and subset of dataset:

```
structure(list(ID = c("13", "13", "13", "13", "13", "13", "13", 
"13", "13", "13", "13", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", 
"14", "14", "14", "14", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", 
"20", "20", "20", "20", "22", "22", "22", "22", "22", "22", "22", 
"22", "22", "22", "22", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", "25", 
"25", "25", "25", "25", "29", "29", "29", "29", "29", "29", "29", 
"29", "29", "29", "29", "39", "39", "39", "39", "39", "39", "39", 
"39", "39", "39", "39", "40", "40", "40", "40", "40", "40", "40", 
"40", "40", "40", "40", "42", "42", "42", "42", "42", "42", "42", 
"42", "42", "42", "42", "44", "44", "44", "44", "44", "44", "44", 
"44", "44", "44", "44", "45", "45", "45", "45", "45", "45", "45", 
"45", "45", "45", "45", "70", "70", "70", "70", "70", "70", "70", 
"70", "70", "70", "70", "84", "84", "84", "84", "84", "84", "84", 
"84", "84", "84", "84", "89", "89", "89", "89", "89", "89", "89", 
"89", "89", "89", "89", "103", "103", "103", "103", "103", "103", 
"103", "103", "103", "103", "103", "104", "104", "104", "104", 
"104", "104", "104", "104", "104", "104", "104", "110", "110", 
"110", "110", "110", "110", "110", "110", "110", "110", "110", 
"111", "111", "111", "111", "111", "111", "111", "111", "111", 
"111", "111", "121", "121", "121", "121", "121", "121", "121", 
"121", "121", "121", "121", "130", "130", "130", "130", "130", 
"130", "130", "130", "130", "130", "130", "141", "141", "141", 
"141", "141", "141", "141", "141", "141", "141", "141", "150", 
"150", "150", "150", "150", "150", "150", "150", "150", "150", 
"150", "160", "160", "160", "160", "160", "160", "160", "160", 
"160", "160", "160", "172", "172", "172", "172", "172", "172", 
"172", "172", "172", "172", "172", "176", "176", "176", "176", 
"176", "176", "176", "176", "176", "176", "176", "193", "193", 
"193", "193", "193", "193", "193", "193", "193", "193", "193", 
"198", "198", "198", "198", "198", "198", "198", "198", "198", 
"198", "198", "206", "206", "206", "206", "206", "206", "206", 
"206", "206", "206", "206", "217", "217", "217", "217", "217", 
"217", "217", "217", "217", "217", "217", "221", "221", "221", 
"221", "221", "221", "221", "221", "221", "221", "221", "230", 
"230", "230", "230", "230", "230", "230", "230", "230", "230", 
"230", "248", "248", "248", "248", "248", "248", "248", "248", 
"248", "248", "248", "252", "252", "252", "252", "252", "252", 
"252", "252", "252", "252", "252", "255", "255", "255", "255", 
"255", "255", "255", "255", "255", "255", "255", "261", "261", 
"261", "261", "261", "261", "261", "261", "261", "261", "261", 
"264", "264", "264", "264", "264", "264", "264", "264", "264", 
"264", "264", "1001", "1001", "1001", "1001", "1001", "1001", 
"1001", "1001", "1001", "1001", "1001", "1002", "1002", "1002", 
"1002", "1002", "1002", "1002", "1002", "1002", "1002", "1002", 
"1004", "1004", "1004", "1004", "1004", "1004", "1004", "1004", 
"1004", "1004", "1004", "1005", "1005", "1005", "1005", "1005", 
"1005", "1005", "1005", "1005", "1005", "1005", "1007", "1007", 
"1007", "1007", "1007", "1007", "1007", "1007", "1007", "1007", 
"1007", "1009", "1009", "1009", "1009", "1009", "1009", "1009", 
"1009", "1009", "1009", "1009", "10010", "10010", "10010", "10010", 
"10010", "10010", "10010", "10010", "10010", "10010", "10010", 
"10014", "10014", "10014", "10014", "10014", "10014", "10014", 
"10014", "10014", "10014", "10014", "10015", "10015", "10015", 
"10015", "10015", "10015", "10015", "10015", "10015", "10015", 
"10015", "10018", "10018", "10018", "10018", "10018", "10018", 
"10018", "10018", "10018", "10018", "10018", "10021", "10021", 
"10021", "10021", "10021", "10021", "10021", "10021", "10021", 
"10021", "10021", "10023", "10023", "10023", "10023", "10023", 
"10023", "10023", "10023", "10023", "10023", "10023", "10025", 
"10025", "10025", "10025", "10025", "10025", "10025", "10025", 
"10025", "10025", "10025", "10028", "10028", "10028", "10028", 
"10028", "10028", "10028", "10028", "10028", "10028", "10028", 
"10032", "10032", "10032", "10032", "10032", "10032", "10032", 
"10032", "10032", "10032", "10032", "10033", "10033", "10033", 
"10033", "10033", "10033", "10033", "10033", "10033", "10033", 
"10033", "10034", "10034", "10034", "10034", "10034", "10034", 
"10034", "10034", "10034", "10034", "10034", "10035", "10035", 
"10035", "10035", "10035", "10035", "10035", "10035", "10035", 
"10035", "10035", "2002", "2002", "2002", "2002", "2002", "2002", 
"2002", "2002", "2002", "2002", "2002", "2003", "2003", "2003", 
"2003", "2003", "2003", "2003", "2003", "2003", "2003", "2003", 
"2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", "2006", 
"2006", "2006", "2006", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", 
"2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "2007", "20011", "20011", 
"20011", "20011", "20011", "20011", "20011", "20011", "20011", 
"20011", "20011", "20013", "20013", "20013", "20013", "20013", 
"20013", "20013", "20013", "20013", "20013", "20013"), Gender = c("Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female"), time = c(0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 
0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 
36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 
120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 
24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 
84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 
18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 
72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 
12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 
60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 
6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 
48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 
0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 
36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 
120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 
24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 
84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 
18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 
72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 
12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 
60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 
6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 
48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 
0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 
36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 
120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 
24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 
84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 
18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 
72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 
12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 
60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 
6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 
48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 
0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 
36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 
120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 
24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 
84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 
18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 
72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120, 0, 6, 
12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 120), Treatment = c("B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), BMI = c(45.2, 33.4976852723098, 
29.7339004102526, 27.8520079792239, 27.4756294930182, 27.0992510068125, 
26.7228725206067, 26.346494034401, NA, 28.2283864654296, NA, 
44.8, 34.5270890725436, 30.8539944903581, 30.8539944903581, 30.4866850321396, 
30.4866850321396, 31.5886134067952, NA, NA, NA, 31.9559228650138, 
40.9, 31.1111111111111, 30.2222222222222, 32.4444444444444, 31.5555555555556, 
32, 32.4444444444444, 32.8888888888889, 33.3333333333333, NA, 
NA, 40.4, 32.9287190082645, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
42.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 31.5886134067952, NA, 40.3, 
29.7339004102526, 27.8520079792239, 26.346494034401, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 40.2, 31.2385898008033, 30.8328938293643, 
31.6442857722423, 30.0215018864863, 29.2101099436083, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 40.1, 25.8805706350208, 24.6181037747759, 23.6712536295922, 
23.355636914531, 24.6181037747759, 26.5118040651433, 27.458654210327, 
26.1961873500821, NA, 27.7742709253882, 50.4, 38.0388841927303, 
34.1142374109407, 33.2085496920662, 31.6990701606086, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 45.3, 32.8719723183391, 31.1418685121107, 30.7958477508651, 
31.4878892733564, 31.4878892733564, 31.1418685121107, 31.1418685121107, 
32.5259515570934, NA, NA, 60.2, 43.4385002286237, 36.5797896662094, 
28.9590001524158, 27.4348422496571, 28.1969212010364, 30.8641975308642, 
30.4831580551745, 32.3883554336229, 33.531473860692, NA, 39.7, 
30.8630068284403, 27.3909185602407, 28.1624937309517, 27.7767061455962, 
26.2335558041742, 27.7767061455962, 26.2335558041742, NA, NA, 
NA, 37, 23.5883292204964, 21.7738423573813, 21.7738423573813, 
21.7738423573813, 22.4996371026274, 23.2254318478734, 23.5883292204964, 
NA, NA, NA, 43.9, 31.6032123735872, 24.5389649018441, 23.7953599048186, 
26.0261748958953, 29.7441998810232, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 40.4, 
33.1397550814291, 26.8274207802045, 26.1961873500821, 26.8274207802045, 
26.5118040651433, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 39.2, 29.7575845550878, 
28.3059950645957, 27.5802003193497, 26.1286108288576, 26.8544055741036, 
25.4028160836116, NA, NA, NA, NA, 36, 24.9770431588613, 22.77318640955, 
22.038567493113, 22.77318640955, 23.5078053259871, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 47.2, 40.6445057337785, 36.2897372623022, 34.1123530265641, 
32.660763536072, 32.660763536072, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 50.1, 38.76698407919, 
34.626820730927, 29.7339004102526, 32.3685498136927, 31.6157928412812, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 51.2, 37.044745057232, 31.633714880333, 29.1363163371488, 
29.9687825182102, 29.9687825182102, 29.1363163371488, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 48.3, 39.1598433606266, 35.9954115739093, 36.7865195205886, 
37.5776274672679, 37.1820734939282, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 53.3, 
43.2622977087005, 40.8588367248838, 39.6571062329755, 39.6571062329755, 
40.0576830636116, 39.2565294023394, NA, NA, NA, NA, 41, 30.8462766729569, 
29.7575845550878, 32.660763536072, 33.386558281318, 33.023660908695, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 39, 28.6989795918367, 24.8015873015873, 22.6757369614512, 
21.9671201814059, NA, 24.4472789115646, NA, NA, NA, NA, 38.5, 
28.6926528494246, 24.4192790207869, 23.8087970452672, 23.1983150697476, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 35.1, 26.5337588296461, 25.8166302126286, 
25.0995015956112, 26.5337588296461, 27.2508874466636, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 45.7, 34.6122448979592, 32.6530612244898, 30.6938775510204, 
29.0612244897959, 28.734693877551, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 45.2, 
28.2283864654296, 24.4646016033724, 25.9701155481953, 25.5937370619895, 
24.4646016033724, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 43.7, 31.8342124153428, 
29.6495115633095, 27.4648107112762, 26.528510346119, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 40, 35.0556317634507, 32.3883554336229, 31.2452370065539, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 41.5, 35.0620891161432, 32.1402483564646, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 47.5, 31.46267227523, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 39.6, 27.4076572777871, 25.2993759487266, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 46.1, 34.4752503991871, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 50.1, 34.4147816499048, NA, NA, 25.7275552140065, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 39.4, 25.0995015956112, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 37.6, 30.4779662232421, 28.6851446806985, 
27.968016063681, 27.2508874466636, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 43.1, 
36.9822485207101, 39.0368178829717, 36.9822485207101, 36.1604207758054, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 43.4, 39.7582052010223, 37.7297253438273, 
36.5126374295103, 36.5126374295103, 34.0784616008763, 34.8898535437543, 
34.8898535437543, NA, NA, NA, 44.1, 39.84375, 39.0625, 37.5, 
37.109375, 36.71875, 38.28125, 37.5, 39.0625, NA, NA, 47.7, 45.3125, 
42.96875, 38.28125, 37.5, 36.71875, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 52.5, 
46.2945102426604, 43.5939971451719, 37.8071833648393, 36.6498206087728, 
40.8934840476833, 40.1219088769723, 45.5229350719494, 46.6802978280159, 
NA, NA, 35.8, 32.8891887333446, 32.0458762017204, 33.7325012649688, 
31.2025636700961, 35.4191263282172, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 19.1, 
18.732782369146, 19.1000918273646, 22.038567493113, 19.1000918273646, 
18.732782369146, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 36.2, 31.2294543063774, 
30.818540433925, 30.818540433925, 32.0512820512821, 31.6403681788297, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 22.6, 22.9440888781548, 24.1516725033209, 
22.9440888781548, 23.2459847844463, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 32.4, 
30.1102788964583, 28.9811434378411, 29.3575219240468, 31.6157928412812, 
31.6157928412812, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 43.2, 39.7370343316289, 
37.9839298758218, 37.399561723886, 35.9386413440467, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 49.9, 44.7908268386634, 41.8047717160859, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 26.6, 24.1415192507804, 23.7252861602497, 
21.6441207075963, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 43.4, 38.724945318943, 
35.8564308508731, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 43.4, 34.9552136325333, 
32.7705127805, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 28.6, 26.6727632982777, 
25.9106843468983, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 37.4, 31.8339100346021, 
28.0276816608997, 26.2975778546713, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
37.4, 30.8630068284403, 33.1777323405733, 32.4061571698623, 30.8630068284403, 
30.0914316577293, 30.8630068284403, NA, NA, 32.4061571698623, 
NA, 45.3, 38.0622837370242, 33.9100346020761, 34.6020761245675, 
36.3321799307959, 37.7162629757785, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 47.4, 
41.0098679994874, 39.3011234995087, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 44.6, 41.914342325865, 41.1522633744856, 38.8660265203475, 
41.914342325865, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 34.9, 32.3232323232323, 
31.5886134067952, 30.8539944903581, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
34.6, 31.2314098750744, 29.3723973825104, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -660L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Why do you not model TIME?

Comment: If you have a look at your data:
data %>%
ggplot(aes(x=time, y=BMI, group=ID, color=interaction(Treatment, Gender))) +
geom_point() +
geom_line()
...then you will see that changes over time differ across the different statistic predictors